# Bipolar Switching Power Supply needed, apparently

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-supply

I'm trying to revive a subwoofer whose power supply broke, and I lack the technical know-how to fix it.
It used to provide both a 5V to the LED and, as I understand it, a VCC of 27 and VEE of -27 volts and the sub is advertised as being "200 watts".

For a short time I thought I can use 2 power supplies to replace the old board, but now I've come to understand that VEE is actually negative and I need a special "bipolar" switching power supply to replace the board.
I don't care about the 5V because the old board already provides that, and worse comes to worse I'll use both of them together.

So my question is, are there ready made boards I can use that can provide the necessary +27 VCC and -27 VEE (and optionally, the 5V) that the old board used to provide?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For a short time I thought I can use 2 power supplies to replace the old board,

Your understanding was correct.

> but now I've come to understand that VEE is actually negative and I need a special "bipolar" switching power supply to replace the board.

Yes, you can use a Bipolar supply. But the end result is the same as using two separate power supplies, each supplying 27 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVA1cc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: That's good news, but how would I connect those 2 to the input of the amplifier that expects -27 volts on one side?

Comment: In series. See the schematic diagrams I added to my answer.